# Token based authentication using Play 2 Framework

Tags: scala, rest, authentication, playframework, http-token-authentication

I'm buiding an application using Play Framework 2, in Scala. It will be purely RESTful, with calls being made at the moment from a Javascript single page application.

What would be the best way to integrate token-based authentication? There are multiple authentication libraries for Play2 out there, plus the raw `Secured` trait, but it's not clear which one would be the most convenient.

Thanks for your help and your suggestions

Answer (score 6):

In case you refer to JWT when you say "token-based", you may want to take a look at [this example](https://gist.github.com/guillaumebort/2328236) of implementing HTTP Basic Authentication in Play2, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23193227/1302490) re: how to implement JWT on a Scala backend. The nice part is that you need neither cookies, nor a cache for authenticated users.

Including content from 1st link for convenience:

```
def Secured[A](username: String, password: String)(action: Action[A]) = Action(action.parser) { request =>
  request.headers.get("Authorization").flatMap { authorization =>
    authorization.split(" ").drop(1).headOption.filter { encoded =>
      new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(encoded.getBytes)).split(":").toList match {
        case u :: p :: Nil if u == username && password == p => true
        case _ => false
      }
    }.map(_ => action(request))
  }.getOrElse {
    Unauthorized.withHeaders("WWW-Authenticate" -> """Basic realm="Secured"""")
  }
}
```

Use as follows:

```
def myAction = Secured("admin", "1234secret") {
  Action { request =>
    Ok
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you should take a look at James Ward's approach [here](https://github.com/jamesward/play-rest-security).

The approach in short is quite straight forward:

1. User requests index page and loads your single-page application
2. Application tries to figure out if there is a security token stored in browser's cookies (or you can use localStorage)
3. If there is no token – login page is displayed
4. If token is present – we think that we're already authenticated
5. App tries to fetch some data from server using token in custom header (like X-AUTH-TOKEN)
6. Server validates token and responds with data if everything is ok
7. If token is not valid server responds with 401, then continue from step 3
8. Every request to your server uses the same token

If you want to go deeper into details, feel free to ask more questions!

Comment: Hi Andrey, thanks for your response. My question was more along the lines of checking authentication in play than on the JS side. I will check today the provided document.

Comment: @ArturSoler I can give you a number of examples on this topic, but you should really check the repository first, probably you'll find everything you need there.

Comment: Sure, I'll check it as soon as possible, later today, and I'll let you know if all my doubts are solved. Thanks again!