# Play Framework & JSON Web Token

Tags: scala, authentication, playframework, jwt

Is there a Scala implementation of JWT or at least an example with Play? After having posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474268/play-rest-and-authentication) I searched further on the Internet and found some intros to JWT. Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am using [Nimbus-JOSE-JWT](https://bitbucket.org/connect2id/nimbus-jose-jwt/wiki/Home) in a [spray.io](http://spray.io/) app and am quite happy with it. The object performing authentication extends HttpAuthenticator and if it finds a correct JWT it returns the token subject and related info, otherwise None (authentication fails). With Play2 you can implement HTTP Basic Auth with something [like this](https://gist.github.com/guillaumebort/2328236). Regarding token setting/getting which I assume is of more interest to you:

First, create a private/public key pair (I used parts of [this code](http://goldenpackagebyanuj.blogspot.gr/2013/10/RSA-Encryption-Descryption-algorithm-in-java.html)). Create the authentication object that loads the keys on initialization from the filesystem.

Create a a com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.MACSigner and a com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.MACVerifier using these keys.

Whenever you want to set a key, FIRST encrypt it, THEN sign it. Encryption:

```
private def encrypt(subject: String) = {
   val header = new JWEHeader(JWEAlgorithm.RSA_OAEP, EncryptionMethod.A128GCM)
   val jwt = new EncryptedJWT(header, claimSet(subject))
   val encrypter = new RSAEncrypter(publicKey.asInstanceOf[java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey])
   jwt.encrypt(encrypter)
   jwt.serialize()
}
```

The claimSet method predictably returns a set of claims:

```
def claimSet(subject: String) = {
   val jwtClaims = new JWTClaimsSet()
   jwtClaims.setIssuer(Config.JWT.issuer)
   jwtClaims.setSubject(subject)
   jwtClaims.setJWTID(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString())
   jwtClaims
}
```

The `publicKey` property is the value returned from `KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic`.

Signing:

```
private def sign(jwt: String) = {
   val jwsObject = new JWSObject(new JWSHeader(JWSAlgorithm.HS256), new Payload(jwt))
   jwsObject.sign(Tokens.signer)
   jwsObject.serialize
}
```

Given the above, when you receive a key you need to verify the signature first, then decrypt it. For verification, first you try to parse it with `com.nimbusds.jose.JWSObject.parse(my_token)` and as long as it doesn't throw a `ParseException` you call `verify` on the JWSObject that `parse` returns, using as an argument the `MACVerifier` that you created earlier. If `verify` returns `true`, you only need to call `getPayload.toString` on the same JWSObject to get the verified payload.

To decrypt the verified payload you call `com.nimbusds.jwt.EncryptedJWT.parse` on it, then something like:

```
val decrypter = new RSADecrypter(privateKey.asInstanceOf[java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey])
jwt.decrypt(decrypter)
```

`privateKey` is the value returned from `KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate`.

You can then get the claim set with `jwt.getJWTClaimsSet`.

Finally, with regard to setting the Authorization header, I'm doing this on my AngularJS client using principles also mentioned in [this post](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/).

Comment: Yes, what you describe is more or less what I did. I use nimbusds too... but I don't encrypt the JWT... I just sign it with the application's secret to ensure it has not been tampered. Since I use HTTPS, token encryption is just a useless overhead. Anyway, thank you very much for your excellent explanation :-)